# Not getting value When trying to get value from a TetBox inside a User Control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview, user-controls

I Created a UserControl (with 2 textbox and 1 label) I have this UserControl inside a ListView. I have a submit button which once is trigger I want to read the values of the (2 textbox and 1 label) For each row of the List View. I have the code below but it does not show me any values when im trying to read what is inside the TextBoxes. What is the correct way of getting the server controls inside the user control?

SpecificExperienceControl.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="SpecificExperienceControl.ascx.vb"   Inherits="TardyAbsenteeReport.SpecificExperienceControl" %>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnID" runat="server" />
<div class="SpecExp">
<tr>
  <td>
   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="SpecExp-txtEmpID" ></asp:TextBox>   
  </td>
  <td>
   <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" CssClass="SpecExp-txtLbl"></asp:Label>
  </td>
  <td>
   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" CssClass="SpecExp-txtAcode"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
</tr>
</div>
```

SpecificExperience.aspx (Use my UserControl on a LIstView That is binded to a xml file to create 25 rows of empty data

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="SpecificExperience.aspx.vb" Inherits="TardyAbsenteeReport.SpecificExperience" %>
```

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
<script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
<LayoutTemplate>
    <table cellpadding="2" width="640px" border="1" runat="server" id="tblProducts">
        <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
          <th id="Th1" runat="server">EmployeeID</th>
          <th id="Th2" runat="server">Name</th>
          <th id="Th3" runat="server">Absentee Code</th>
        </tr>
        <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
</table>         

</LayoutTemplate>                    
<ItemTemplate>
   <hr:SpecExp ID="SpecExp1" runat="server"></hr:SpecExp>     
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
<div>
   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

SpecificExperience.aspx.vb (code to trying to read the data from the server controls inside the User Control

```
 Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim lview As ListViewItem

    For Each lview In ListView1.Items

        Dim LblEmployeeName As Label = lview.FindControl("SpecExp1$Label1")
        Dim TxtEmployeeID As TextBox = lview.FindControl("SpecExp1$TextBox1")
        Dim TxtAbsenteeCode As TextBox = lview.FindControl("SpecExp1$TextBox2")

        Dim StrEmployeeId As String = TxtEmployeeID.Text
        Dim StrLblemployee As String = LblEmployeeName.Text
        Dim StrAbsentee As String = TxtAbsenteeCode.Text

    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you checking if postback occurred? It sounds like maybe you are not and the listview is freshly binding on each button click.